# handling scene sizes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, resolution, scene

I am playing with SpriteKit in xCode 6.* using Swift for iOS and am struggling to find out how to implement multiple device versions.

The latest setup of a sprite kit scene uses a .sks file to instantiate the SKScene. This sets the scene size using parameters set in the .sks file.

1. Does this mean that a different sks file is required per device?

where:
 iPhone 5s - 568x320
 iPhone 6 - 667x375
 iPhone 6 plus - 736x414

2. How would I ensure the correct sks file was loaded for each device in the ViewController, i'm taking a stab at UIDevice and a conditional?
3. How does this affect multiple levels, Would it be one .sks per level per device?

Comment: You shouldn't need to make a different sks file for each device. If you have a gameplay area which is independent of screen size, then scale it to fit on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Use one `sks` file and allow it to scale on the other devices. Check out [`SKScene`'s `scaleMode` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKScene/scaleMode) to see your options.

You may have some other adjustments to make in code based on screen size, but this should be your starting point, with a single `sks` file.